# Selenium - Edge (Chromium) browser - Direct option to set default download path

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, microsoft-edge, chromium

Is there a direct way to set default download path for the Edge (Chromium) browser like how we have for chrome,firefox browsers

Sample snippet (for chrome):

Map pref = new HashMap();
 pref.put("download.default_directory", "Path to download");

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", pref);

Comment: prefs = {"profile.default_content_settings.popups": 0,
                 "download.default_directory": r"C:\Users\user_dir\Desktop\\",
                 "directory_upgrade": True}
        options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
        return webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=Base.chromedriver_dir, chrome_options=options)

Answer (score 1):

Here I am assuming that you are using the latest stable version of the Edge Chromium browser.

I am showing you the example for C# project.

I suggest you add a reference to [Microsoft.Edge.SeleniumTools](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Edge.SeleniumTools)

```
using Microsoft.Edge.SeleniumTools;

namespace selenium_IE_automation
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var options = new EdgeOptions();
            options.UseChromium = true;
            options.BinaryLocation = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe";   // Here add the Edge browser exe path.
            options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", @"D://");                    // Here add the download path.
            var driver = new EdgeDriver(@"D:\D drive backup\selenium web drivers\edgedriver_win64 81.0.416.68", options); // Here add the selenium web driver path.
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

References:

1. [Set download directory via WebDriver](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/discussions/set-download-directory-via-webdriver/m-p/1340286)
2. [Selenium Tools for Microsoft Edge](https://github.com/microsoft/edge-selenium-tools)

Note: If you are developing using any other language then you can try to convert the above code to that language to make it work.

**Edit:**

This is the example using the JAVA language. It uses Selenium 4.

This solution is tested with the MS Edge Chromium 81.0.416.72 version.

```
public class new_java_class {

        public static void main(String[] args) {


                  System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver","D:\\D drive backup\\selenium web drivers\\edgedriver_win64  81.0.416.72\\msedgedriver.exe");

                  Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();

                  prefs.put("download.default_directory",
                  System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "externalFiles" + File.separator + "downloadFiles");

                  EdgeOptions op=new EdgeOptions();
                  op.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);

                  WebDriver browser = new EdgeDriver(op);

                  browser.get("https://microsoft.com");

        }

}
```

Comment: Setting 'UseChromium = true;' option is not working in java version.Is there any other way for Selenium 3.x ?

Comment: I try to refer to the documentation and it only shows the ways to implement this library for C# and Python. I did not get the way to add this library to the JAVA project. I noticed in the docs that this functionality is by default added to Selenium 4. so if you are available to use the Selenium 4 then it may help to solve this issue.

Comment: Please see my updated answer. I have shared the example for the JAVA language using Selenium 4 to set the default download folder for the Edge Chromium browser. Let me know if you have any further questions. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Has somebody succeeded doing this with python?

Answer (score 0):

Starting from selenium 4, there is no need to import Microsoft.Edge.SeleniumTools, the function in `Microsoft.Edge.SeleniumTools` had already been a part of selenium 4 edge options